# Why can we change indices when defining covariant derivative formula?

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, covariance, differential

For $ \overrightarrow{V} = V^i \overrightarrow{e_i} = V_i \overrightarrow{e^i} $,

$ \frac{\partial \overrightarrow{V}}{\partial x^j} = \frac{\partial V^i}{\partial x^j} \overrightarrow{e_i} + V^i \frac{\partial \overrightarrow{e_i}}{\partial x^j} = \frac{\partial V^i}{\partial x^j} \overrightarrow{e_i} + V^i (\Gamma^k_{ij} \overrightarrow{e_k}) $

Yes, I get it until here. But I don't understand how are we able to switch dummy indices i and k only for the second term of the last side so it becomes $ \frac{\partial V^i}{\partial x^j} \overrightarrow{e_i} + V^k (\Gamma^i_{ki} \overrightarrow{e_i})  = (\frac{\partial V^i}{\partial x^j} + V^k \Gamma^i_{kj}) \overrightarrow{e_i} $. Shouldn't i in the first term also be changed to k?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a double sum
$$
\sum_i V^i \sum_k \Gamma^k_{ij} e_k = \sum_{i,k} V^i\Gamma^k_{ij}e_k
$$
and if you relabel the dummy variables $i,k$ as, lets say, $\alpha,\beta$, you end up with
$$
\sum_i V^i \sum_k \Gamma^k_{ij} e_k = \sum_{\alpha,\beta} V^{\alpha}\Gamma^{\beta}_{\alpha j}e_{\beta}
$$
which now becomes, by relabelling $\alpha,\beta$ as $k,i$,
$$
\sum_i V^i \sum_k \Gamma^k_{ij} e_k = \sum_{i,k} V^k\Gamma^i_{kj}e_i.
$$
Hence,
\begin{align}
\sum_i \left( \partial_jV^i e_i + V^i\sum_k\Gamma^k_{ij}e_k \right)
&= \left(\sum_i\partial_jV^ie_i\right) + \left(\sum_iV^i\sum_k \Gamma^k_{ij}e_k\right) \\
&= \left(\sum_i \partial_jV^ie_i\right) + \left(\sum_{i,k} V^i\Gamma^k_{ij}e_k\right) \\
&= \left(\sum_i \partial_jV^ie_i\right) + \left(\sum_{i,k}V^k\Gamma^i_{kj}e_i \right) \\
&= \left(\sum_i \partial_jV^ie_i\right) + \left(\sum_i\sum_kV^k\Gamma^i_{kj}e_i\right)\\
&= \sum_i\left( \partial_jV^i + \sum_{k}V^k\Gamma^i_{kj}\right)e_i.
\end{align}

If you don't understand, look at an easy example with only two terms.

Comment: I know how it works on the second term where we partial differentiate basis. What I want to know is the reason why is i in the first term not being switched to k.

Comment: @posfn0319 See the edit. The two sums are independent, so you can relabel one without relabelling the other.

Comment: I got it. Thanks so much!